# Pot player playlist bug

Tags: daum-pot-player

If I have more than 9 video files in some folder,Pot Player will only list 9 in the playlist. I have to manually add other files
This is a long standing bug (for years)
Additionally, when I drag and drop new files to the playlist, list order is messed up

I have to manually every time click sort by ==> title
Is there any fix/workaround for this? Maybe in settings?

Comment: Very product-specific question... have you contacted the devs?

Comment: @spikey_richie I tried signing up to forum, but can't get verification email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I have more than 9 video files in some folder,Pot Player will only list 9 in the playlist. I have to manually add other files This is a long standing bug (for years)*

How are you adding the files into Potplayer? For me I just Ctrl + A and Drag and drop the whole thing, or you can drag the folder into Potplayer and that should show all videos.
If some aren't showing possibly Potplayer doesn't detect the format, you can probably try amending those files properties to default play with Potplayer test 1 and see if that works

*Additionally, when I drag and drop new files to the playlist, list order is messed up*

This can be fixed by Right click -> Preference -> Expand the Playback option and go to Playlist, then check the box for "Sort dropped files before adding to list"

Comment: thx for the second part, that works fine... I'm opening one file from folder with double-click, usually the rest of the files are read automatically...sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

I  think I had the same issue. I had 12 items in my folder while PotPlayer opened only 3, no matter what.

Yo make it open all files head to:

Preferences => General => When files opened: Add all the files

I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

for me, i'm having issue when dragging the file to the playlist, where the file have a very long path. (Not able to find the file)
but double click to open the file works. (There seems to be some path shortening here).

Not sure if there is any way to resolve this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1081159)